# Работа с битовыми операциями в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, битовые-операции

**Задача:**

> Реализуйте метод flipBit, изменяющий значение одного бита заданного
>   целого числа на противоположное. Данная задача актуальна, например,
>   при работе с битовыми полями.
>
> Договоримся, что биты нумеруются от младшего (индекс 1) к старшему
>   (индекс 32).

**Пример ввода/вывода:**

```
Sample Input:
0 1
Sample Output:
1
```

**Мое решение:**

```
public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {
    return value ^ bitIndex; // put your implementation here
}
```

Что не так с моим решением ? Проверял на [BitwiseCmd](http://bitwisecmd.com/). Вроде все правильно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Понял в чем дело. Ответ будет таким:

```
public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {
    return value ^ (1 << bitIndex-1); // put your implementation here
}
```

***Решение по пунктам:***

1. `bitIndex-1`, т.к. нумерация начинается с нуля.
2. `(1 << bitIndex-1)` - здесь мы сдвигаем единицу влево на нужное число бит (это число `bitIndex-1`)
3. `value ^ (1 << bitIndex-1)` — меняем нужный бит, т.к., например, при `01011011101^0001` получаем  `01001011101`.