# побитовые сдвиги

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Условие задачи:

> Реализуйте метод `flipBit`, изменяющий значение одного бита заданного целого числа на противоположное.Договоримся, что биты нумеруются от младшего (индекс 1) к старшему (индекс 32).

А вот его решение:

```
public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {
    return value ^ (1 << bitIndex-1);
}
```

Вопрос: никак не могу понять что происходит здесь:

```
(1 << bitIndex-1)
```

разъясните пож-а.

Comment: происходит битовый сдвиг числа `1` налево на величину `bitIndex-1`, после чего его через XOR применяют к исходному числу (оператор `^`)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с битовыми операциями в Java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565116/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос: никак не могу понять что происходит здесь:
>   (1 << bitIndex-1)

Происходит  сдвиг битов влево (или тупо возведение двойки в степень) `bitIndex-1`

На самом деле более подробно можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603545/191482)

Вкратце 1 можно представить примерно как `00000001`

`<<` — побитовый сдвиг влево

в итоге например если `bitIndex` равно 3, то `1 << 3` (смещаем единицу на три разряда влево) получается

```
00001000 // 8
```

а при `bitIndex - 1` получается соответственно:

```
bitIndex - 1  → 1 << 2 → 00000100 // 4
```

Хотя в итоге чему равно значение в десятичной системе не важно, но это просто, на заметку

Comment: вот мне все понятно) кроме как зачем  "bitIndex - 1" писать если если я хочу сделать побитовый сдвиг влево,вправо на 3 бита, то я напишу 3 бита, если на 2 то напишу 2. зачем этот доп.арифметический шаг. сознание замылилось уже не вижу надобности в этом минус 1

Comment: @SergioBerluskony видимо потому, что крайний правый бит имеет позицию 0. Как и, к примеру, массивы начинаются с нуля. Поэтому говоря о том, что мы хотим манипулировать с 1-ым битом в человекопонятном видении (обычные человеки не привыкли что что-то начинается с нуля, они привыкли с единицы отсчет вести),  значит мы хотим работать с крайним справа, а он в "строке" `00000001` на самом деле начинается с нулевой позиции в программистском мире..... поэтому вычитаем единицу...... ну с остальными по аналогии

Comment: долго же до меня доходил этот "bitIndex - 1", а ведь все просто: в данном случае, то что для людей является вторым для машины является 3-им.

Comment: @SergioBerluskony именно. но вообще так-то нужно для себя определиться и для других определить каков будет начальный индекс... 1 == 0 или как полагается в программировании 0 == 0....... в общем в данном случае автор сего скрипта решил сделать так

Answer (score 1):

Происходит сдвиг битов влево, на место новых битов становятся нули. По сути это возведение двойки в степень.

1 << 5 // 100000 или 32

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос: никак не могу понять что происходит здесь:
>
> ```
>    (1 << bitIndex-1)
> ```

Здесь происходит сдвиг битов в `1` влево на `bitIndex-1` позиций.